# converting perl script to c++(cppgen) file

Tags: perl

I have this file `mk-colors.perl` that makes an unorderedmap of rgb colors.
In my makefile I try to do this:

```
  all : ${EXECBIN}
    - checksource ${ALLSOURCES}

  ${EXECBIN} : ${OBJECTS}
     ${COMPILECPP} -o $@ ${OBJECTS} ${LINKLIBS}

  %.o : %.cpp
     ${COMPILECPP} -c $<

  colors.cppgen: mk-colors.perl
     mk-colors.perl >colors.cppgen
```

However it seems like the perl script is not compiling correctly, this code worked fine on my work's server, but when I copied to my localmachine the perl wont compile into a cppgen file. I am runing XUbuntu 12.04, do I need to install anything new? Thanks

EDIT:
I keep getting this error:

```
./mk-colors.perl: invalid line: ! $Xorg: rgb.txt,v 1.3 2000/08/17 19:54:00 cpqbld Exp $`
```

here is the perl code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# $Id: mk-colors.perl,v 1.3 2014-05-21 15:40:52-07 - - $
use strict;
use warnings;

my %colors;
my $file = "/usr/share/X11/rgb.txt";
open RGB_TXT, "<$file" or die "$0: $file: $!";
while (my $line = <RGB_TXT>) {
  $line =~ m/^\s*(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(.*)/
     or die "$0: invalid line: $line";
  my ($red, $green, $blue, $name) = ($1, $2, $3, $4);
  $name =~ s/\s+/-/g;
  $colors{$name} = [$red, $green, $blue];
  }
  close RGB_TXT;

  print "// Data taken from source file $file\n";
  print "const unordered_map<string,rgbcolor> color_names = {\n";
  printf "   {%-24s, rgbcolor (%3d, %3d, %3d)},\n",
              "\"$_\"", @{$colors{$_}}
   for sort {lc $a cmp lc $b} keys %colors;
    print "};\n";
```

Comment: The script is compiling fine.  You're getting a runtime error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `die` statement is executing:

```
$line =~ m/^\s*(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(.*)/
   or die "$0: invalid line: $line";
```

This indicates that there is some data in `/usr/share/X11/rgb.txt` that isn't in the format you were expecting.  Open up this file, find the offending line, and figure out how to patch your Perl script to handle it properly.

Comment: Not only that, the error message is showing the data and the regular expression clearly doesn't match.